# Selenium/Serenity Bdd - drag and drop of element always end up at top left corner position

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

```
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
```

Test 1

```
actions.clickAndHold(containerRuleset).moveByOffset(50,50).release().build().perform();
```

Test 2

```
actions.dragAndDrop(containerRuleset, canvasWorkflow).perform();
```

Test 3

```
actions.moveToElement(containerRuleset, 135, 10).perform();
```

Test 4

```
actions.dragAndDropBy(containerRuleset, 60, 50).perform();
```

I had try to drag and drop an element into a canvas in another division,
By moving in small offset(within the original element div ), I can see it's moving

But when i try to move into another div, the location always went to the top left of current parent div without any error, which causing it fail to drop in target div.

Are there any limitation to consider when work with drag and drop from a div into another div?
such as the absolute path/division path, then width and length type of the ui, the parent div setting

Answer (score 0):

Just able to solve this by Drag two time
-so the first time after drag it will reallocate into the top left position
-then the second time when it drag it will drag to expected location